# SUMPRODUCT multiple criteria columns & rows but ignore blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This formula results with #VALUE! error as some columns and/or rows are blank. Is there a way to get a result while keep blanks in the data sheet?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Data!$E$2:$JN$200*(Data!$A$2:$A$200=$B8)*(Data!$E$1:$JN$1=M$3))
```

Comment: Sample data/screenshot would really help - subject to providing this for future users, a google sheet would be great for those answering the first time... (noting I mentioned subject to.. i.e. google sheet alone not helpful when/if link breaks/changes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j99w7Crw4tVyxezWR0?e=V4fKA6) / screenshot refer:
[image: Sample - working soln]

Per screenshot - I have plenty of blanks yet your equation is working perfectly...

HOWEVER, if I place text in the sumproduct range (viz: E2:JN200) then I get an error which I can circumvent as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(Data!$E$2:$JN$200*(Data!$A$2:$A$200=$B8)*(Data!$E$1:$JN$1=M$3),0))
```

[image: Screenshot 2 - formula for cell C19...]

Comment: This worked since I added IFERROR after SUMPRODUCT and ,0)) at the end. Thanks.